# DialogFragment does not occupy bezel less screen

Tags: android, android-dialogfragment

I am trying to display a dialog fragment in a bezeless phone which has a notch.
Here is the screenshot.

[image]

As you can see the dialog fragment does not occupies the whole screen and show an ugly grey color at the top.

Here is what i have tried

I am setting the style in DialogFragment

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setStyle(DialogFragment.STYLE_NORMAL, R.style.FullScreenDialogStyle)
    }



<style name="FullScreenDialogStyle" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Dialog">
        <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
        <item name="android:windowIsFloating">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowLayoutInDisplayCutoutMode">shortEdges</item>
    </style>
```

I am using the same technique for Activity Screen and it works as it occupies the whole bezelless screen but this does not work for dialog fragment

Comment: how did you manage to show full screen view for activity ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You have two options here. First, let's look at the components that are common to both options;

DialogFragment's onStart method:

```
override fun onStart() {
    super.onStart()
    val dialog: Dialog? = dialog
    if (dialog != null) {
        val width = ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT
        val height = ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT
        dialog.window?.setLayout(width, height)
        dialog.window?.decorView?.systemUiVisibility =
                View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY or
                View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION or
                View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN
    }
}
```

DialogFragment's onCreate method:

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setStyle(DialogFragment.STYLE_NORMAL, R.style.FullScreenDialogStyle)
    }
```

Dialog xml:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent"
              android:background="#c92145">

    <Button android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:text="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

FullScreenDialogStyle:

```
<style name="FullScreenDialogStyle" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="android:windowLayoutInDisplayCutoutMode">shortEdges</item>
</style>
```

**Options:**
[image: options]

***Left (Option #1)***

Add this line to FullScreenDialogStyle

```
<item name="android:fitsSystemWindows">true</item>
```

***Right (Option #2)***

Add this line to FullScreenDialogStyle

```
<item name="android:fitsSystemWindows">false</item>
```

Comment: Best working solution! Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

In your code, you should include android "**windowMinWidthMajor**" and "**windowMinWidthMinor**" properties and set dialog.getWindow() layouts to MATCH_PARENT and make the layout in LinearLayout.

```
<style name="Theme_Dialog_tab" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Dialog">
        <item name="android:windowMinWidthMajor">100%</item>
        <item name="android:windowMinWidthMinor">100%</item>
        <item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowIsFloating">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@null</item>
    </style>
```

In Java file:

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity(),R.style.Theme_Dialog);

dialog.getWindow().setLayout(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
```

I hope it will help you....!

Comment: Thank you for your help, I tried your solution but it does not work. I am using a Dialog Fragment and not an AlertDialog.

Answer (score 0):

I found another simple solution, just try to put this code on onCreate() method :

```
Dialog yourDialog;

if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.P) {
    yourDialog.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS );
    yourDialog.getWindow().getAttributes().layoutInDisplayCutoutMode = WindowManager.LayoutParams.LAYOUT_IN_DISPLAY_CUTOUT_MODE_SHORT_EDGES;
}
```